# Why does merging an indentical commit with a different lineage work?

Tags: git, git-merge

Common best practices say to never merge a feature branch which after it has been rebased. But it looks like if the contents of the rebased branch match exactly commits on the target branch, rebase will be able to do a clean merge. Why will this sequence work without producing merge conflicts because the first and second merges are merging the same changes but with different commits?

```
git init --initial-branch=prod
git commit --allow-empty -m 'initial commit'
git checkout -B test_a prod
git checkout -B test_b prod
git checkout test_a
echo hello > testing_file
git add testing_file && git commit -m "add testing file"
echo goodbye > testing_file
git add testing_file && git commit -m "update testing file"
git checkout test_b
git merge test_a
git checkout test_a
git rebase -i prod # squash commits
git checkout test_b
git merge test_a
```

How does this

```
commit c65182aad4b07c272b527888f8e0780854dee39b
Merge: 070cb78 1bf92cd
Author: REDACTED
Date:   Wed Apr 6 11:22:55 2022 -0400

    Merge branch 'test_a' into test_b

commit 070cb7828cf2216ed5b0edaa62fb3815824397ae
Author: REDACTED
Date:   Wed Apr 6 11:21:43 2022 -0400

    Squash

diff --git a/testing_file b/testing_file
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..dd7e1c6
--- /dev/null
+++ b/testing_file
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+goodbye

commit 1bf92cd210ac92b94a9b0b250e7705201117619d
Author: REDACTED
Date:   Wed Apr 6 11:21:44 2022 -0400

    update testing file

diff --git a/testing_file b/testing_file
index ce01362..dd7e1c6 100644
--- a/testing_file
+++ b/testing_file
@@ -1 +1 @@
-hello
+goodbye

commit 2aa3f8a3637550d4b5c48e408da00c519450762b
Author: REDACTED
Date:   Wed Apr 6 11:21:43 2022 -0400

    initial commit

commit 4388bd254b58b4be0e8e50293c78f489efb2eaaa
Author: REDACTED
Date:   Wed Apr 6 11:21:43 2022 -0400

    add testing file

diff --git a/testing_file b/testing_file
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..ce01362
--- /dev/null
+++ b/testing_file
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hello
```

Comment: In my experience,  git does _not_ produce conflicts when the same change is coming from the different branches being merged.

Comment: In fact, here, it goes beyond that: when you do the second merge, the state of the repo in both branches is identical. Empty diff == no conflict, every time.

Comment: Even if there are extra commits on test_b it's a clean merge (e.g. adding `echo hello > other_file && git add other_file && git commit -m "update other file"` as the second to last command)

Comment: @LeeAvital Why would you expect having new commits touching a *different* file would cause a merge conflict on `testing_file`? Merge conflicts happen when you edit the same file in different ways on the two branches you are trying to merge.

Comment: It might be conceptually easier to understand if you do something that causes a conflict, and then compare the two scenarios to identify the difference between them.

Comment: `Common best practices say to never merge a feature branch which after it has been rebase` - what does this sentence mean? If there’s a common practice relevant to the question please add a reference. (Please address by editing the question).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps some common best practices are based on incomplete understanding, or oversimplified (maybe deliberately and maybe for good reasons—I wouldn't know) models, and/or simple [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).  The key to the *Git* part of this is to identify these three commits:

- merge base
- current commit
- other commit

and then to inspect (or in this case, imagine) the two diffs you would get by running:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-base> HEAD
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-base> <hash-of-other>
```

> it looks like if the contents of the rebased branch match exactly commits on the target branch ...

Technically, until you define the word *branch* at least, a "branch" does not have contents.  A *commit* has contents (metadata and snapshot), and here we can assume that:

> contents of the rebased branch

means "the snapshot of the other commit" (`$other` below) and

> match exactly commits on the target branch

means "the snapshot at the tip of the current branch" (the `HEAD` commit), or vice versa.  In that case, pick any merge base commit hash `$B` and run:

```
git diff --find-renames $B HEAD > /tmp/diff1
git diff --find-renames $B $other > /tmp/diff2
```

and inspect the diff hunks.  Since `git diff HEAD $other` is *empty* (`HEAD` and `$other` have the same snapshot by our assumption here), these two diff outputs will match, *regardless of which specific commit we choose as `$B`*.  Git will therefore be trivially able to combine the two diffs, by taking one copy of all of the changes shown, and apply those changes to the snapshot in `$B`, giving the snapshot that appears in both `HEAD` and `$other`.

This will be the snapshot of the resulting merge.  The merge commit made *by* `git merge`, if any, will depend on the ancestry—the is-ancestor and hash equality relationship between `$B` and `HEAD`—and whether we used `--no-ff` and/or `--squash` in our `git merge` command, but the merge *process* will be trivial, no matter what.

#### The key insight

The key to understanding this lies in the fact that `git merge` depends only on *those three commits*.  Any *intermediate* commits are irrelevant:

```
          I1--I2--I3--I4--L   <-- leftside (HEAD)
         /
...--o--B
         \
          I5--I6--I7--I8--R   <-- rightside
```

(assuming `git switch leftside && git merge rightside` here).  Git will compare the snapshots in `B`, `L`, and `R` *only*.  The snapshots in the eight `I` (irrelevant) commits take no part in the merge-as-a-verb work-combining action.  Only the diffs from `B` to `L` and from `B` to `R` matter here.